# Declare variable in bash function? (BASH)

Tags: bash

I have this:

```
sum() for i in $@; do ((tot += 4)); echo $tot;done
```

Now, how do i reset the tot variable before the for-loop?

I tried:

```
sum() tot = 0; for i in $@; do ((tot += 4)); echo $tot;done

sum() tot = 0;done; for i in $@; do ((tot += 4)); echo $tot;done

sum() tot = 0 for i in $@; do ((tot += 4)); echo $tot;done

sum() ((tot = 0)) for i in $@; do ((tot += 4)); echo $tot;done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function definition requires a single compound command as its body. This is legal

```
sum() for i in $@; do ((tot += 4)); echo $tot;done
```

because your `for` loop is that single compound command. As soon as you try to add *another* command (in this case, the assignment to `tot`), you need to ensure both that command and the `for` loop are combined in *another* compound command.

The usual way to define a function is to always use a brace group (or in certain situations, a subshell `(...)`), even if the only command inside the brace group is another compound command. Here, the brace group allows you to add your assignment statement to the body of the function:

```
sum () {
    tot=0
    for i in "$@"; do ((tot += 4)); echo "$tot"; done
}
```

---

Your first two attempts are errors because a single assignment statement is not a valid function body.

Your third attempt is an error because compound commands (unlike simple commands) cannot be preceded by a variable assignment.

Your fourth attempt is syntactically legal; it defines a function `sum` that sets the value of `tot` to 0. The `for` loop is executed after the function is defined, rather than being part of the function definition.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make the variable `tot` local to the function with the `local` keyword:

```
sum() { local tot; for i in $@; do ((tot += 4)); echo $tot;done; }
```

optionally, when defining a local variable, you can also set an initial value:

```
sum() { local tot=0; for i in $@; do ((tot += 4)); echo $tot;done; }
```

but this is optional here.

Comment: It might be a good idea to make `tot` a local variable, but that doesn't actually solve the original problem. Ensuring the assignment and the `for` loop are all part of a single compound command (inside the `{...}`) does.

Comment: Might as well make the `i` variable local too.